# Can't open the light covers in the fan

Tags: electrical

[image][image]

Tried opening the light covers but it's not opening in the conventional way, even two of the electricians were not able to open it. Please need help. The globe is held by three tension clips and turning it counterclockwise or other way nothing is working. Need to change the bulb because the lights are out. Hampton bay sidewinders model AC4054-5.[image]

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [the manual](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/85/85686dde-a04b-4dbf-a126-1c9d56c40e22.pdf), turn anticlockwise while pulling lightly downward (i.e. the opposite of installing it).

[image]